# R language how to do optimization with either/or constraints?

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I am trying to do constrained optimization using R. My constraint is not continuous. Here is an example:

```
minimize: f(x,y)=(x-2)^2+y^2
st. x=0 or x>=3
y=0 or y>=2
```

What type of optimization problem is this?

Comment: If you graph the domain I think you will find that it is continuous.

Comment: It is continuous but no longer convex. Interestingly, the convexity can be handled by discrete optimization techniques.

Answer (score 2):

These are called semi-continuous variables. Some solvers support these directly, but they can also be formulated with additional binary variables:

```
 3*d <= x <= 1000*d
 d binary
```

Anyway, you end up with a MIQP model (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming). Solvers like Gurobi and Cplex support this and have R interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Erwin! I have several questions. Since x is larger than 3, can we still use the binary coding? Seems it only applies to <=3. Besides, how to code the binary variable in the constraint anyway?

Comment: `d` can assume only two values: 0 or 1. If 0 it follows that `x=0`. If 1 we have `3<=x<=1000`. This is a very standard formulation. How to tell the solver the variable `d` is binary, is solver and API dependent.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. I see the binary works perfectly if x falls bewteen 3 and 1000. But if I just want to set x to be 0 or >=1000, can we still use the binary coding?

Comment: Semi-continuous variables allow bounds `[L,Infinity)`. The binary variable approach requires some upper bound, e.g. `1000*d <= x <= 100000*d`. In practical applications we always know a reasonable upper bound.

Comment: It makes sense. Semi-continuous variable seems works for my case. I found LpSolve deals with this problem. However, my objective function is nonlinear but not necessarily quadratic (it can be y^4.5 rather than y^2). Seems many solvers including Gurobi only deals with linear and quadratic function rather than more complicated objective function? Is there any other R package available to deal with it?

Comment: I am not aware of MINLP solvers that run directly under R. I typically use modeling systems like GAMS and just exchange data/results with R. In some cases you can use piecewise linear formulations to approximate nonlinear functions in Gurobi.